# Great Pacific Garbage Patch Equilibrium Points

Tags: vector-fields, oceanography

I originally posted this question on earth science stack, but the question wasn't getting many views.

I was watching the science channel yesterday and the program mentioned the Great Pacific Garbage Rim. I was struck by the illustration (and pretty much every subsequent animation/picture I've seen now has the same basic illustration) below:[image]

Unless I'm not understanding something, the garbage swirls around in a huge  closed trajectory and encloses two sinks (the colorful swirly things; one on the left and one on the right). This shouldn't be physically possible though, with the perfectly reasonable assumption that the vector field that currents produce is continuously differentiable. Any closed curve has to enclose equilibrium points who's indices add to $+1$, but a sink has an index of $+1$ so this curve encloses a total of $+2$. There would have to be at least one other equilibrium point inside the closed trajectory that had an index of $-1$, so something like a saddle node:

[image: ![enter image description here]

But I can't find any illustrations showing any other equilibrium points other than these two. Does anyone know where and what type they are, or perhaps if I'm not understanding something?

Comment: I suspect what you are missing is that there are two vector fields that matter here: ocean currents and wind.  Stuff on the surface will be influenced by both and may accumulate in places which are not obvious from analysis of each independently.

Comment: I don't agree with @tfb : we can simply consider the vector field F(x) = "which way the garbage is going at x". I also don't think that the garbage patches are actual sinks in the sense that F = 0 there, but that in fact F is pointing slightly to the east/west at the western/eastern patch (with an actual zero somewhere in the middle). If the curve was not so eccentric it would simply look like a circular flow with an index in the middle. But I'm just guessing.

Comment: @crestmods: you are right, I was wrong